# How do I set custom/mock location in Android?

Tags: java, android, location

I have made an App that shows up a location searched by a user.Now I want to set the location searched by a user as a current location in such a way that the Android system assumes that this particular location is the current location.Now whatever the apps(Fb,Twitter,Quora... Etc) installed in a device must read this location as current location.How do I achieve this?

Does this work for above requirement?

private void setMockLocation(double latitude, double longitude, float accuracy) {

```
    lm.addTestProvider (LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,
            "requiresNetwork" == "",
            "requiresSatellite" == "",
            "requiresCell" == "",
            "hasMonetaryCost" == "",
            "supportsAltitude" == "",
            "supportsSpeed" == "",
            "supportsBearing" == "",
            android.location.Criteria.POWER_LOW,
            android.location.Criteria.ACCURACY_FINE);      

    Location newLocation = new Location(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);

    newLocation.setLatitude(latitude);
    newLocation.setLongitude(longitude);
    newLocation.setAccuracy(accuracy);

    lm.setTestProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, true);
    lm.setTestProviderStatus(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,LocationProvider.AVAILABLE,null,System.currentTimeMillis());      
    lm.setTestProviderLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, newLocation);      
}
```

Comment: Couldn't get it. Can you elaborate your requirement?

Comment: @TabrejKhan Thanks for your try.I want to set my own location instead of current/actual location, In such a way that all the Apps installed on a device must read the location set by me.It is more like location mockery or fake location.